# Finding the amount of solutions in a 3 equation solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

So, I'm not really sure how to calculate the amount of solutions for a system with 3 equations.

All I know is that it has something to do with matrices and the discriminant, but I'm not sure where to go with that.

- EDIT

Here's the system that I'm working on:

$$x+2y+3z=7$$
$$3x+4y-z=4$$
$$3x+2y-11z=-13$$

Comment: Can you post the actual system in question?

Comment: @Amzoti It's added now

Comment: Have you learned Gaussian Elimination? You either get no, one or infinite solutions. Hint: in this case you get the last row of all zeros. What does that tell you? Can you tell this from the determinant?

Comment: Um. It means that there are infinite solutions right?

Comment: Yes, it means you typically get a bunch of free variables. Can you do the GE and show that?

Answer (score 1):

We have the system $$x+2y+3z=7$$
$$3x+4y-z=4$$
$$3x+2y-11z=-13$$

The associated *augmented coefficient matrix* is given by:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3&|&7\\3 & 4 & -1 &|&4 \\ 3 & 2 & -11 &|& -13\end{pmatrix}$$

Use Gaussian Elimination (row reduction using elementary row operations). If you encounter a row with all zeros, then you'll know there are infinitely many solutions. You'll have an inconsistent system, for which there are NO solutions, if you obtain a row such as $$(0\;0\;0\;|\; a)$$ where $a \neq 0$. Otherwise, the system will have one unique solution.

If you row reduce correctly, you should obtain a reduced row form as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -7  &|& -10 \\ 0 & 1 &5 & | & \frac{17}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &|&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thanks Amzoti!

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 7 \\
    3 & 4 & -1 & 4 \\
    3 & 2 & -11 & -13
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 7 \\
    0 & -2 & -10 & -17 \\
    0 & -4 & -20 & -34
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 7 \\
    0 & -2 & -10 & -17 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$0=0$$

Infinite amount of solutions

Comment: Uh, I'm not so sure how to do that part